# Where to find String::lines implementation?

Tags: java

I have found https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200425 that talks about new `String::lines` method.

I would like to have a look at the implementation of the function. The problem is, I don't really know where to find it. I have already tried to look at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk but with no luck.

Does anybody know where the implementation is?

Comment: This seems to be on OpenJDK11, given the link you just gave

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/2fb27c352cae

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no implementation yet. If there was you should be able to find it here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

The issue you have linked is the CSR (Compatibility & Specification Review) of the actual issue that implements it:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200380

Which is still unresolved. (It looks like they're waiting for [raw string literal library support](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196005) to be done first)

Comment: the related issue has a comment saying "approved", so I guess it's available *somewhere*, not yet to the public. I tried searching in the repositories...

Comment: @Eugene Afaik that's just the specification/proposal that's "approved"

Comment: @Eugene The link was to the latest revision on the jdk master branch. It was only ever meant to be valid at the time of posting the answer. I should have made that more clear. If you go here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/ and click on `browse` on the left then navigate to `/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java` you'll get the latest version, which does currently contain the `lines` implementation (I don't know how to make a link to `String.java` that is always up to date). P.S. Found it, and added to the answer :)